# Sysadmin related Twitter tags

Tags: untagged

What are your favorite (active!) tags for sysadmin related things?

Examples (obviously MS biased...):

```
#sql
#sqlserver
#windows
#microsoft
```

Comment: Dunno why it was voted down. I don't use twitter much but know people who do and this could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have at one time or another used the following as stored searches, in order of interest, roughly.

```
#opschef, or #opscode #chef
#puppet
#rails
#rubyonrails
#serverfault :-)
#infosec
#hosting
#vps
#debian
#redhat
#automation
#scripting
#perl
#cpan
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#linux
#apache
#mysql
#php
```

Answer (score 1):

`#netbackup`
`#cognos`
`#microsoft`
`#linux`

Answer (score 1):

```
#omgihatehashtags
```

---

I jest, ones I've seen:

```
#osx
#macosx
#it
#bofh
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of times, I just use #sysadmin